# What is the difference between include_directories and interface_include_directories with headers only library

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to understand the difference between the scope that one can specify in `target_include_directories`, specifically `PRIVATE` and `INTERFACE`. The documentation says (the specific context is *header only library*):

> The INTERFACE, PUBLIC and PRIVATE keywords are required to specify the
>   scope of the following arguments. PRIVATE and PUBLIC items will
>   populate the INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property of . PUBLIC and
>   INTERFACE items will populate the INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
>   property of . (IMPORTED targets only support INTERFACE items.)
>   The following arguments specify include directories.

So basically using either `PRIVATE` or `INTERFACE` modifies `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` or `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`. I do struggle to understand the difference between the two of them. From the description in the doc `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` seems to be the argument of the flag `-I` when compiling a C++ project.

I don't understand at all the latter instead, can anyone clarify?

Also apparently using `INTERFACE` is better when using headers only library, why is that?

Answer (score 6):

Interface targets is for headers only libraries. Declaring such target will not produce any content at compile time (CMake will not generate rules to produce objects,  executables or library for these targets).

Thus, CMake need to differentiate headers that will be used to compile targets that produce objects.

As I remember, the main use of these 2 properties is the following: (please note that I'm not 100% sure of everything).

**An executable target**

- Can have the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property set with the list of directories needed to compile files for this target
- Cannot have `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` set, because other targets cannot depends on an executable target (*I'm not sure about that*)

**A library target**

- Can have the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property set with the list of directories needed to compile files for this target
- Can have the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` set with a list of directories needed to compile other targets that depends on this target

**An interface target**

- Cannot have `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property set because it will never be compiled
- Most probably have the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` set because it contains only header files, so other targets that depends on will need to include those headers

Since this is a difficult question, and many people are asking this, I will turn this answer into community answer ASAP so by iterative refinement we will hopefully find a way to correctly explain this point.

Comment: I find a bit weird there's no explanation either in the CMake documentation, not a proper one at least.

Comment: But as far as I'm understanding it's a matter of what kind of target we're aiming to build.

Comment: Yes and no. You may want to declare a library that can be used as dependency by another target, without declaring any include directory that should be added when compiling that dependent target. `PUBLIC`, `PRIVATE` or `INTERFACE` modifiers to `target_include_directory` will only determine how the include directory will be used (by curent target and other targets depending on it)

Comment: But I agree, CMake documentation is definitely a pain. It's a great tool, but I saw a huge number of people hating it, mostly because understanding it's internal behavior is often a nightmare

Comment: @Antwane The answer is not completely correct. For the library target, the directories in `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ` are also used to build this target. At least this is what I observed with my CMake (3.7.2) installation.

Answer (score 1):

There are two containers of the target to contain the directories that included by the target.​

The first container is called **INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES**, which contains all the directories that are **included only** by the target itself;​

The other container is called **INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES**, which contains all the directories that are **not** included by the target itself, but are included by the other targets which depend on the current target;​

​

If the keyword PRIVATE is used, then the directories will be saved in container one, **INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES**, which are only included by the target itself;​

If the keyword INTERFACE is used, then the directories will be saved in container two, **INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES**, which are not included by the target itself. But included by the other targets which depend on the current target.​

If the keyword PRIVATE is used, then the directories will be saved in both containers. Then the current target and the targets depend on the current target all include these directories.​

The post below gives a more detailed answer related to this question.

At least it helps me to understand the differences between private/public/interface.

Thanks a lot again for the original author!

[CMake: Public VS Private VS Interface](https://leimao.github.io/blog/CMake-Public-Private-Interface/)